# Google Chrome Address Bar Font has gone too large, how can we reduce it

Tags: unity, google-chrome, fonts

Running Unity on my desktop (2*20" LCD displays), I initiated a standard daily update on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS today and Google Chrome updated itself to Version 35.0.1916.114.

The URL address bar input now shows IMO a too larger font size which then proceeds to auto show in green. I prefer the smaller font size and have no need for 'gooey slime green' auto complete font colours.
Any advice on how to revert back to smaller, generic Address font styling.

I use both FF and Chrome for numerous tasks, Chrome being my primary browser and I've checked my system Unity 'default' theme (Ambiance! LOL.. yes I'm tired of that also).

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

As part of Chrome 35, Chrome has switched to the Aura framework and is no longer using GTK. Some of the UI changes are due to the change to Aura, while other changes are by design.

As far as I know, the font size within the Omnibox can't be changed, and the colors likely cannot be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That clears up that point. I will wait a few days until I accept this answer. I may also look to other browsers or Open Source Chromium as an alternative.Thanks again.

Comment: Chromium also uses Aura, and therefore also has the slightly-larger font.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Google Chrome bug and there is [a workaround for it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375824#c65).