# Chrome has gone too large after update ubuntu 14.04 ..?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Chrome has gone large in all senses - the whole window, tabs, font. See the picture below.

I tried this following suggestion on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470065/google-chrome-address-bar-font-has-gone-too-large-how-can-we-reduce-it), but not luck fixing it.

All I did is this:

```
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 11'
- google-chrome
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 13'
```

Here is my return to `google-chrom --version` `Google Chrome 43.0.2357.124`

[image]

Comment: When you say all you did was `- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 11'
- google-chrome
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 13'`, what exactly do you mean? Did you run that in Terminal? Or...?

Comment: yes, ctrl+alt+t -> copy and paste one link at a time. I run it as sudo as well. I wasn't sure If i need it or not..

Comment: So to try to fix the problem you ran each of those line by line?

Comment: Just to add a bit more weight to my question, look like there was a actual bug posted on [chrome releases page](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/06/stable-channel-update_11.html)  and here is another comment on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/39gui9/the_chrome_stable_channel_has_been_updated_to/) about this issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me the following worked:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

make sure you kill all running instances of google chrome, otherwise it will just open another (broken) window ignoring the command line parameters

Comment: I thank all of the users who has contributed to this discussion. My problem has been fixed using the command above.

Answer (score 4):

solution is to add flag  `--force-device-scale-factor` in the file `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` or in `/usr/bin/google-chrome`

For solving error in **chromium browser**, I added the following line

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --force-device-scale-factor=1"
```

after the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` definition in the script `"/usr/bin/chromium-browser"`, *( for me it was line 185 )*

for `/usr/bin/google-chrome` you should add the same parameter but in other way, *( sorry on my side the bug was only on chromium )*

Comment: A similar change to _Session and Startup » Application Autostart » Chromium_ worked for me in Xubuntu after an update.

Comment: You should better use ~/.chromium-browser.init , because /usr/bin/chromium-browser will be overwritten on browser package update.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran an update and the problem resolved as part of the update.

Version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit)

Update Chrome.

Comment: Same here. `google-chrome-stable amd64 43.0.2357.125-1` fixed the issue. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @NotMy1RealName thanks for the answer, but I couldn't find the where to download the latest chrome .125-1..  All found is [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/43.0.2357.125) I'm guessing your built from source..? I'm sure how to do that. If you know there to get `.deb` package I will much appreciate that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the

```
$CHROMIUM="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --force-device-scale-factor=1"
```

modification, however it did not work. Instead, I used @fetteelke's suggestion, and just ran the following commands:

```bsh
cd /usr/bin
sudo echo '#! /bin/bash' | tee /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-hack
sudo echo '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1' >> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-hack
sudo chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-rtisma-hack
sudo mv  google-chrome-stable  google-chrome-stable.backup
sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-hack  google-chrome-stable
```

and now everything is working fine. I am using the latest Ubuntu release.