# chrome resolution changes when monitor is turned off

Tags: google-chrome, monitor, display-resolution, dpi

Having an issue with Google Chrome resolution/dpi changing when I turn my monitor off. I'm pretty sure that this is all related to the **scaling factor from Universal Access Panel.** in which I have **large text** turned on. This setting makes Chrome have bigger tabs, but is not recognized when monitor is turned off. I have to shut down Chrome, and restart it it to recognize the Universal Access setting.

To see what is going on with my display settings while my monitor is turned off I used `xrandr'.

The output of `xrandr` while monitor is **ON** is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     30.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9
```

The output of `xrandr` while monitor is **OFF** is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1280x720       60.0 +   50.0     30.0     59.9     30.0     24.0     24.0  
   4096x2160      24.0     24.0  
   3840x2160      30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080      60.0*    50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9
```

In any case I  would like to figure out how to keep chrome's dpi/resolution stable so that I don't have to restart it each time my monitor is turned off/on. Here are two screenshots of before and after.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Please note that the second photo is what Chrome would look like if I did NOT have Universal Access with **large text** turned ON.

Something interesting that I noticed is that in this larger mode (second photo), the buttons and navigation don't actually correlate to the items on the screen. If I click any of the bookmark bar icons at the top with the mouse, the browser would not navigate to the right one. For example, if I clicked on the UTUBE short cut in the bookmarks bar it would take me to the $$$ link. It seems to be behaving as though the object & frame mappings are still 'calibrated' for when the scale was bigger.

Comment: Interesting question! I'll chew on it a bit. The ration indeed seems much different from just a dpi - interpretation

Comment: Although.... I'll do some proper measuring when I get home! 890 <> 708 is quite a difference.

Comment: @JacobVlijm thank you so much for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: You're welcome, it's interesting!

Comment: In the meantime, found this: `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1316847` does the command `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Interface app-fallback-to-maximum-scale-factor false` change anything? (I might be thinking in the opposite direction, but this is a quick idea).

Comment: Ah, shoot, I mix up chromium with chrome...

Comment: What's your chrome version? are you using this version 43.0.2357.124?

Comment: 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) -and now running  50.0.2661.94 (64-bit)
. Teh problem will happen with any version as it is Chrome not obeying the scaling factor from Universal Access Panel.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think I have narrowed it down. Please see updated question about UNIVERSAL ACCESS.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid if this is true it should be fixable! I need some time to look into it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that Chrome has changed to the Aura framework, and no longer uses GTK framework.

A simple workaround is to launch Chrome with:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.5
```

Comment: You did it! Great job.

Comment: @JacobVlijm i am receiving notices about having to award the bounty, despite that it was not me who posted it (i think it was you). I see no way to do that, so how should we proceed on this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Wow, only, when I post, it is kind of a copy of your answer, and you did the final work, just let me know what you suggest :)

Comment: No, you did *all* the work!

Comment: @JacobVlijm    i dont know your cALL

Comment: I would love the bonus, but I think in this case, it would be unfair to claim it. It is a pitty of your 50,  but I shouldn't produce an answer that is actually yours. Again, you did a great job.

Comment: @JacobVlijm TAKE THE MONEY AND RUN!

Comment: OK, posted :), I will elaborate a bit afterwards :) You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/470373/72216), Chrome has changed to the [Aura framework](http://jessealtman.com/2013/12/introduction-to-aura/), and no longer uses GTK framework. This causes however some peculiarities.

As mentioned by Kalamalka Kid, who actually did practically all of the work, it can be worked around by running Chrome with the command:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=<scale_factor>
```

e.g.:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.5
```

#### How to make Google Chrome start by default with the changed scale factor

1. Copy the global `Google-chrome` launcher from `/usr/local/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the local copy with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```

   Look for the line: `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`, change it into:

   ```
   google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.5
   ```

Now after you log out/in, `Chrome` starts by default in your altered scaling.

Comment: theres a new similar problem with the new 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) of Chrome. I noticed after upgrading that this solution no longer works the same, as the object mapping is relative to the old resolution (but the resolution problem is ok). If i run Chrome with `google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.5` from Terminal it works fine, but not when launched from icon (which has been edited to have `/usr/bin/google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.5` thoughts?

Comment: ok fixed it. There were actually 3 entries with EXEC= in the latest .desktop file that needed to be modified. They were for main, new window, and incognito launch. What i am gooing to do is simply save a backup copy of the modified .desktop file and replace it with every upgrade of Chrome. I think that should work.

Comment: Most likely, if you copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`, you won't have to change unless there is a major update.

Comment: can you invite me to chat for a second? i dont know how to do this

Comment: @KalamalkaKid sure! we have one still: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39381/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-jacob-vlijm